# regex exclude matches that don't meet one of two patterns separated by delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript using `string.match()`:

I have a string like: `foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong`

the matches should look like `["foo_2:asc", "foo2:desc", "foo3"]`

but instead the best I can get it to so far is a match returning `["foo_2:asc", "foo2:desc", "foo3", "wrong"]`

the regex that I'm using currently for the above wrong match is: `/([a-z0-9_]+?[:asc|:desc]*?)(?=,|$)/gi`

I also need a regex that will return the opposite, i.e. find a match for all patterns between the delimiter that doesn't match the pattern rules of `thing_1:asc`, `thing_1:desc`, or `thing_1` i.e. this would be used to validate the string, while the other would be used to gather the values (i.e. instead of splitting the string manually).  So the result of the original would be `["foo4:wrong"]` as the part of that string that doesn't meet the pattern.

Comment: What makes `foo4:wrong` wrong?

Comment: are they always separated by comma `,` in between? Or can they be anything at all? So basically you want 1 or more alphanumberic or underscore by itself, or if followed by `:asc` or `:desc`?

Comment: in my case, they are always separated by comma, but i would imagine if someone wanted to do this and use a different delim, they shouldn't need much of a change to get it working for them.  but yes, you are correct @nopole

Comment: so `@&%@=` and `@G&%=@` would be considered a match for the "opposite"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the only valid forms are words followed by one of `:asc`, `:desc` or nothing, you can do what you want by splitting the string, first on `,` and then on `:` and checking whether there are two values as a result of the last split and the second is not one of `asc` or `desc`:

```js
const str = 'foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong';
const errs = str.split(',').filter(v => v.split(':').length == 2 && ['asc', 'desc'].indexOf(v.split(':')[1]) == -1);
console.log(errs);
```

If you must use regex, you can split on `,` and then filter based on the value not matching `^\w+(:(asc|desc))$`:

```js
const str = 'foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong';
const errs = str.split(',').filter(v => !v.match(/^\w+(:(?:asc|desc))?$/));
console.log(errs);
```

If the format of the string is guaranteed to be `\w+(:\w+)?(,\w+(:\w+)?)*` you can simplify to this:

```js
const str = 'foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong';

const errs = str.match(/\w+:(?!(?:asc|desc)\b)\w+/g);
console.log(errs);
```

Comment: the idea is to use regex for this though

Comment: Why over-complicate it?

Comment: what happened to your answer? it worked for me to find the bad string

Comment: @Jubair I removed it again because it is wholly dependent on the format of each term being *exactly* `\w+(:\w+)?` and I don't know for sure that is the situation. If that is correct I can put it back in again...

Comment: basically the term is a mapping to a database table column name, so alpha numeric with `_` as a possible character, so your solution did work in the tests I ran.

Comment: @Jubair I've added a more robust regex solution

Comment: @Jubair I've also added back the original regex solution with an appropriate caveat

Comment: cool thanks! yea I opted to just use regex for the error match, but for breaking up the string I ended up going with: `string.split(',').map(row => row.split(':')).reduce((o, [k, v]) => ((o[k.trim()] = (v || 'asc').trim()), o), {});` to deconstruct the string into key/value object.  though now that I Think about it, I can prob use mapReduce, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Jubair nice piece of deconstruction! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the match I came up with

```
/(?<=(^|,))((\w+(?!:)|\w+(:asc|:desc)))(?=($|,))/g
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/QLJeDV/3/

```
> "foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong".match(/(?<=(^|,))((\w+(?!:)|\w+(:asc|:desc)))(?=($|,))/g)
[ 'foo_2:asc', 'foo2:desc', 'foo3' ]
```

Or even

```
/(?<=(^|,))\w+(:asc|:desc)?(?=($|,))/g
```

should work. Example: https://regex101.com/r/QLJeDV/6/

```
> "foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong".match(/(?<=(^|,))\w+(:asc|:desc)?(?=($|,))/g)
[ 'foo_2:asc', 'foo2:desc', 'foo3' ]
```

They are using lookahead and lookbehind.

For the "opposite", I don't know how to match something and then "negate" a later pattern, but only know how to negate the result of whether it is a complete match, so I had to split it.  The "opposite":

```
> "foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong".split(",").filter(s => !/^((\w+(?!:)|\w+(:asc|:desc)))$/.test(s))
[ 'foo4:wrong' ]
```

and the "original":

```
> "foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong".split(",").filter(s => /^((\w+(?!:)|\w+(:asc|:desc)))$/.test(s))
[ 'foo_2:asc', 'foo2:desc', 'foo3' ]
```

Or it can be simplified as:

```
> "foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong".split(",").filter(s => !/^\w+(:asc|:desc)?$/.test(s))
[ 'foo4:wrong' ]

> "foo_2:asc,foo2:desc,foo3,foo4:wrong".split(",").filter(s => /^\w+(:asc|:desc)?$/.test(s))
[ 'foo_2:asc', 'foo2:desc', 'foo3' ]
```

Comment: thanks for the detail! I ended up going with the negative pattern match in the accepted answer, and then simply used `split, map, reduce` to get the values from any valid string later on in the code path.

Comment: for 45 minutes spent, with several possible solutions, I don't even get a single upvote. That's a really nice experience

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like regex for this purpose, you probably can just add **start from** *coma* or *string start*.

```
/(^|\,)([a-z0-9_]+?(:asc|:desc)*?)(?=,|$)/gi
```

also pay attention [:asc|:desc] changed to (:asc|:desc), to avoid false positive cases like:

```
foo5:aaa,foo6:d,foo7:,foo8|,et:c
```

it just matches by any char in square brackets.

Regarding opposite, try something like:

```
/(^|\,)(?!([a-z0-9_]+?(:asc|:desc)*?)(?=,|$))[^,$]+/gi
```

seems to do the job.